How to prevent xfce4-screensaver segfaults when weston running?
I run Xubuntu 22.04.4 with X11.
I am playing with waydroid which needs Wayland (about which I know very little).
I start weston from inside my X session (weston --shell=kiosk-shell.so --width=600 --height=1050 &) and then enable the lockscreen (xflock4).
When I then hit a key to bring up the password prompt, I just get a black screen, and can see the backlight turning on and off rapidly and a cursor flashing occasionally if I try typing blindly.
I type Ctrl+Alt+F1, login and do pkill weston, then Alt+F7 back to X. Now hitting a key successfully brings up the password prompt and I can unlock.
If I look in /var/log/syslog I see segfault messages like:
May  8 11:49:53 imp kernel: [336276.448749] xfce4-screensav[331764]: segfault at 500000084 ip 00007f26e536052f sp 00007ffcf60bec20 error 4 in libgdk-3.so.0.2404.29[7f26e5324000+83000]
May  8 11:49:53 imp kernel: [336276.448761] Code: 57 82 fc ff 49 8b 9c 24 70 01 00 00 48 85 db 74 4e 49 89 c5 eb 0a 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 85 db 74 3f 48 8b 2b 48 89 de 48 8b 5b 08 <48> 8b 45 08 48 85 c0 74 e8 4c 39 e8 7f e3 49 8b bc 24 70 01 00 00
May  8 11:49:53 imp xfce4-screensav[2995]: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
May  8 11:50:03 imp kernel: [336286.457039] xfce4-screensav[331769]: segfault at 41a00000270 ip 0000558e05fb6e59 sp 00007ffce7e81350 error 4 in xfce4-screensaver-dialog[558e05fb2000+e000]
May  8 11:50:03 imp kernel: [336286.457050] Code: 48 8d 74 24 30 4c 89 e7 e8 c4 cb ff ff 8b 4c 24 38 44 8b 44 24 3c 4c 89 ef 89 4c 24 1c 44 89 44 24 10 e8 7a dc ff ff 4c 89 ef <44> 8b 60 18 e8 6e dc ff ff 44 8b 4c 24 08 44 8b 44 24 10 4c 89 ff
May  8 11:50:05 imp kernel: [336288.451531] xfce4-screensav[331783]: segfault at 41a00000270 ip 0000558c0fc40e59 sp 00007fff7a3b9d50 error 4 in xfce4-screensaver-dialog[558c0fc3c000+e000]
May  8 11:50:05 imp kernel: [336288.451541] Code: 48 8d 74 24 30 4c 89 e7 e8 c4 cb ff ff 8b 4c 24 38 44 8b 44 24 3c 4c 89 ef 89 4c 24 1c 44 89 44 24 10 e8 7a dc ff ff 4c 89 ef <44> 8b 60 18 e8 6e dc ff ff 44 8b 4c 24 08 44 8b 44 24 10 4c 89 ff
May  8 11:50:08 imp kernel: [336291.776860] xfce4-screensav[331796]: segfault at 41a00000270 ip 0000561864ab6e59 sp 00007ffcdd5faf50 error 4 in xfce4-screensaver-dialog[561864ab2000+e000]
May  8 11:50:08 imp kernel: [336291.776870] Code: 48 8d 74 24 30 4c 89 e7 e8 c4 cb ff ff 8b 4c 24 38 44 8b 44 24 3c 4c 89 ef 89 4c 24 1c 44 89 44 24 10 e8 7a dc ff ff 4c 89 ef <44> 8b 60 18 e8 6e dc ff ff 44 8b 4c 24 08 44 8b 44 24 10 4c 89 ff
May  8 11:50:15 imp kernel: [336298.150297] xfce4-screensav[331809]: segfault at 41a00000270 ip 00005577ab541e59 sp 00007ffc4ec8c5d0 error 4 in xfce4-screensaver-dialog[5577ab53d000+e000]
May  8 11:50:15 imp kernel: [336298.150308] Code: 48 8d 74 24 30 4c 89 e7 e8 c4 cb ff ff 8b 4c 24 38 44 8b 44 24 3c 4c 89 ef 89 4c 24 1c 44 89 44 24 10 e8 7a dc ff ff 4c 89 ef <44> 8b 60 18 e8 6e dc ff ff 44 8b 4c 24 08 44 8b 44 24 10 4c 89 ff
May  8 11:50:15 imp kernel: [336298.330052] xfce4-screensav[331822]: segfault at 41a00000270 ip 0000556835bfee59 sp 00007ffc167fb700 error 4 in xfce4-screensaver-dialog[556835bfa000+e000]
May  8 11:50:15 imp kernel: [336298.330063] Code: 48 8d 74 24 30 4c 89 e7 e8 c4 cb ff ff 8b 4c 24 38 44 8b 44 24 3c 4c 89 ef 89 4c 24 1c 44 89 44 24 10 e8 7a dc ff ff 4c 89 ef <44> 8b 60 18 e8 6e dc ff ff 44 8b 4c 24 08 44 8b 44 24 10 4c 89 ff
May  8 11:50:15 imp kernel: [336298.546376] xfce4-screensav[331834]: segfault at 41a00000270 ip 0000559d5867be59 sp 00007fff0a18bdd0 error 4 in xfce4-screensaver-dialog[559d58677000+e000]
May  8 11:50:15 imp kernel: [336298.546386] Code: 48 8d 74 24 30 4c 89 e7 e8 c4 cb ff ff 8b 4c 24 38 44 8b 44 24 3c 4c 89 ef 89 4c 24 1c 44 89 44 24 10 e8 7a dc ff ff 4c 89 ef <44> 8b 60 18 e8 6e dc ff ff 44 8b 4c 24 08 44 8b 44 24 10 4c 89 ff
[...]

What do I need to do so that unlocking my X session works while weston is active?

File a bugreport? Problem is with "error 4 in libgdk-3.so" and as far as I can tell it is a version mismatch between 2 tools. Most fixes are about installing  GTK3.

@Rinzwind I've now reported - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-screensaver/+bug/2065234

@Rinzwind my system has packages that include gtk2, gtk3 and gtk4 in their names, all installed automatically. Are you saying that is a documented problem?

I found a clue at https://github.com/waydroid/waydroid/issues/593 :
If I give a socket option to weston (e.g. weston --socket=waydroid), then the lockscreen problem goes away.
Subsequently, waydroid can be invoked as: WAYLAND_DISPLAY=waydroid waydroid show-full-ui
